# By pass lookup filter with apex code

Tags: deployment, controller

I have to deploy some classes in production, but in test class, in which i am creating dummy records, i am getting error with lookup filters
Account has two lookup from contact i.e. "account MAnager" and "negotiator", in lookup filter, there is condition of not empty,
also, we cannot create contact because , account lookup is mandatory filed there,
means we can not create account without contact and also contact can not be created without account, there is problem of kind of deadlock
i can not disable lookup filter in production,
how can i insert the account by bypassing those lookup filters

Comment: I wonder, can anyone wade in here with the possibility of using a static resource to load test data - does that bypass required fields? Outside the scope of my experience.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you have created a deadlock situation there, I don't think there is a particularly reliable or stable way to bypass this to create test data. One option (which I don't like) is to use the `@isTest(SeeAllData=true)` annotation - [which you can read up on here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_seealldata_using.htm) - which would allow your tests to be run using the existing data in your organisations.

I think a better solution is to "fix" your data model though. Do these fields need to be "required" lookups in this fashion? Are ALL Accounts dependant on these two contact lookups (account manager and negotiator?) - could you perhaps use Validation rules (in conjunction with a picklist value or record type) to enforce their completion, rather than required at a field level?

Depending on your system, could you make the contact lookup fields Required via the page layouts instead? (make sure you consider all aspects of data integrity for this though)...

[image: Required Field]

This would allow you to programmatically create data without hitting these rules.

It's hard to answer any more completely without more information on your system/setup. But these are the sorts of things I would consider to overcome your problem.

Comment: Thanx Simon, but we can not change any setting in production for now, and @isTest(SeeAllData=true) is creating problem since i have developer sandbox, not full sandbox